# Show that $(f_n)_n$ is fundamental but not convergent in X in relation to $||\cdot||_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In the linear space $X=\mathcal{C}_{[0,1]}$ we define: 
$||\cdot||_1:X\to\mathbb{R}, ||f||_1=\int_0^1|f(x)|dx$ 
Consider the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}, (n\ge3)$
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
0, x\in\big[0, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\big] \\
\frac{nt}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4}, x\in\big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\big) \\
1, x\in\big[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}, 1\big]
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $(f_n)_n$ is fundamental but not convergent in X in relation to $||\cdot||_1$

tl;dr on what I tried:
Let $m\le n\implies ||f_n-f_m||_1 =$
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}\bigg(\frac{(n-m)x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n-m}{4}\bigg) +\int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}\bigg(1-\frac{mx}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{m}{4}\bigg)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4m}$$
Does this show that $(f_n)_n$ is not convergent since it's not $0$ and fundamental because.. yeah? Thanks in advance

Comment: $f_n$ and $f_{n + k}$ differ only on an interval of length $\dfrac{1}{2n}$ by an amount of at most 1, so it is a fundamental sequence in $\mathsf{C}_{\mathbf{R}}[0,1]$ with the $\mathscr{L}^1$-norm. Further, $f_n = f_{n + k}$ on $(0, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}) \cup (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}, 1),$ so $f_n$ converges pointwisely to $f$ where $f = 0$ on $(0, \frac{1}{2}),$ $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f = 1$ on $(\frac{1}{2}, 1).$ This convergence is, in fact, in $\mathscr{L}^1$ but since $f \notin \mathsf{C}_\mathbf{R}[0,1],$ the convergence is not in the latter (just the former) space.

Comment: Just to clarify a point in my previous comment, I am stating that $\|f_n - f_{n + k}\|_\infty \leq 1$ and $f_n = f_{n + k}$ except on $(1/2 - 1/n, 1/2+1/n)$ so that $$\|f_n - f_{n+k}\|_1 \leq \|f_n - f_{n+k}\|_\infty \int\limits_{[1/2 - 1/n, 1/2 + 1/n]} dt = 1/2n \to 0.$$